# Raphaël-ZPD click to zoom in/out

Tags: svg, click, zooming, raphael

Does anyone know how to trigger zoom in/out with Raphaël-ZPD by clicking on a button?

Comment: Can you put a jsfiddle up for someone to have a play with to help ?

Comment: I just saw that Raphaël-ZPD is not supported in IE 10. At least it doesn't work for me. You could recommend some other plugin, appropriate for this purpose, if there is such.

Comment: What about http://code.google.com/p/svgpan/ or http://dashasalo.com/2011/04/13/svg-image-zooming-and-panning-with-raphaeljs/ also play around with  setViewBox()

Answer (score 0):

If take a look to the code of Raphael-ZPD you would see that all the zooming and panning are made by using svg matrices. In the particular case of zooming, it first draw a reference point where the mouse is, and calculates the zoom direction relative to that point, using the delta of the mouse wheel to apply the amount of zoom.

Now, if you want to use a button, you would have to decide the delta on your code, and you could maybe use the center of the screen as the relative point to calculate the direction of zooming.

For starters you could just use the svg scale property, something like this could be ok if you are using Raphael ZPD:

```
paper = Raphael('container',600, 600);
paper.ZPD({ zoom: true, pan: true, drag: false });

scale = 1;
var zoomin = document.getElementById('in')
var zoomout = document.getElementById('out')

zoomin.onclick = function(){
    scale *= 1.2
    paper.canvas.setAttribute("transform", "scale("+scale+")")
}

zoomout.onclick = function(){
    scale *= 0.8
    paper.canvas.setAttribute("transform", "scale("+scale+")")
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4PkRm/) is Fiddle with a working example

I reccomend to add some translate calculating the center of the screen, so the zoom doesn't go to corner. But  think all this could point you in the right direction.